# Reading Co-ordinates from a Text File in C++

Tags: c++, text-files, coordinates, file-io

OK, so all I am trying to do is simply read some co-ordinates from a text file and use them to draw an array of bricks. I have this code:

```
ifstream infileScenario("scenario1.txt");

for (int i = 0; i < NUM_OF_BRICKS; i++)
{
    // read brick coordinates
    infileScenario >> bricks[i].m_x;
    infileScenario >> bricks[i].m_y;
    cout << bricks[i].m_x << "   " << bricks[i].m_y << endl;

    // set brick properties
    bricks[i].m_height = 0.1;
    bricks[i].m_width = 0.2;
    bricks[i].life = 3;
}

infileScenario.close();
```

But the only thing that I am getting printed to the console is a bunch of 0's. I've checked over my code again and again as well as double checking my text file and I still can't see where I am going wrong.

My text file is called scenario1.txt and it's contents are:

```
-0.6 0.7

-0.3 0.7

0 0.7

0.3 0.7

0.3 0.7

-0.6 0.5

-0.3 0.5

0 0.5

0.3 0.5

0.3 0.5
```

I wrote these values in myself which, if I had to hazard a guess, would think what could be causing my problem. Could it be to do with text encoding or am I wrong in thinking this?

Comment: What are the types of the `m_x` and `m_y` members?

Comment: Hopefully, text encoding is not so messed up that even *plain ASCII* needs re-encoding! You are reading floats; in what type of variables? If they are stored into `int`, or if you are printing them to the console as `int`, you'll never see the floating point  numbers.

Comment: That for-loop is blatantly ignoring the nearly-guaranteed failures that are happening in your value extractions. You make no checks that the file even successfully opened, much less that the values were each pulled with success.

Comment: m_x and m_y are floats.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest not using the stream classes, they are a little more difficult to check for errors, here is the same code converted (with error checks) using fscanf.

```
FILE *infileScenario;
int i;

if ((infileScenario = fopen("scenario1.txt", "r")) == NULL) //didnt open readonly
{
    printf("Error, could not open scenario1.txt\n");
    exit(-1); //terminate program with a code we can read by running echo $?
}
for (i = 0; i < NUM_OF_BRICKS &&
            fscanf(infileScenario, "%lf %lf",
                   &bricks[i].m_x, &bricks[i].m_y) != EOF;
    i++)
{
    // read brick coordinates
    printf("%lf %lf\n", bricks[i].m_x, bricks[i].m_y);
    // set brick properties
    bricks[i].m_height = 0.1;
    bricks[i].m_width = 0.2;
    bricks[i].life = 3;
}

fclose(infileScenario);
```

You can also g++ -g -o   and then gdb  and run the following in gdb:

```
b main
r
s
(each time the for loop hits bricks[u].life = 3, run)
p bricks[i]
(otherwise, keep running)
s
```

That should allow you to diagnose what the issue seems to be, if my solution did not just fix it.

Comment: I tried your code and although it didn't fix my problem it immediately highlighted what it was: I hadn't placed my text file in the correct directory so it wasn't being loaded. A bit embarrassing really... but at least I've learnt an alternative to using an ifstream.

Comment: yeah, fstreams kinda suck...they are simple for beginners, but you seem like you can handle it